# Finishing the game but not at 100%

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

It is not nescesery to kill every boss in every district to be able to fight El Sueño. The bare minimum is 8 total boss fights before the big guy. If I finish the game in this way and skip more than half the bosses, would I be able to then go back and fight every one of them or is it if I kill El Sueño it's credits and thanks for playing ?

Comment: Considering that there are two endings, I'm going to say yes. My reasoning is because of the way you unlock the endings. I 100%ed the entire game before going after Sueño. After that mission, a prompt pops up saying you can redo the mission for the alternative ending. That's what makes me think you can go back and finish up the game after doing the Sueño mission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. After you complete the El Sueño mission, you will receive a prompt saying that you did not 100% complete the game and you will be allowed to go back to complete those other missions.  Once you have 100% completed the game (all bosses and all side missions), the other ending will unlock (so play the EL Sueño mission again).

Comment: source - happened to me

Comment: I did this also